# Android custom dialog with MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm, retrofit, customdialog, android-livedata

I am creating custom dialog and i want when the user click add button go and call retrofit and observe on changes but i don't know how to pass lifecycleowner to the observer

```
 private void observeViewModel(ProjectListViewModel viewModel) {
        // Update the list when the data changes
        viewModel.getProjectListObservable().observe( ***what to pass here ??*** , new Observer<List<Project>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Project> projects) {
                if (projects != null) {
                    //…
                    projectAdapter.setProjectList(projects);
                }
            }
});
```

thanks in advance

Comment: you should pass `this` over there. because your activity is LifeCycleOwner

Comment: If passing `this` is not working try extending `LifeCycleActivity`

Comment: could not pass this since i am extending "Dialog" and this not a LifeCycleOwner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution. It worked for me.

Create a field of your activity from where you are calling the dialog and pass this in place of lifecycleowner

```
public class YourDialog extends DialogFragment {

private YourActivity activity;

    public static YourDialog newInstance(YourActivity activity) {
        YourDialog dialog = new YourDialog();
        dialog.activity = activity;
        return dialog;
    }

    private void observeViewModel(ProjectListViewModel viewModel) {
    // Update the list when the data changes
    viewModel.getProjectListObservable().observe( activity , new Observer<List<Project>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Project> projects) {
            if (projects != null) {
                //…
                projectAdapter.setProjectList(projects);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

You can refer the example of mvvm [here](https://github.com/husaynhakeem/TicTacToe-MVVM) if you want