# How to show custom DialogFragment using Android Jetpack Navigation?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am building a game for Android using Kotlin, MVVM and Android Jetpack. Recently I have been trying to show DialogFragments using Navigation component. My *navigation.xml* file:

```
<dialog 
    android:id="@+id/gamePauseDialog"
    android:name="pl.kamilszustak.innymislowy.dialog.GamePauseDialog"
    android:label="GamePauseDialog" />
```

Anyway, my custom dialog has got 4 buttons inside, which have got their own onClickListeners:

```
interface OnButtonsClickListener : DialogInterface.OnDismissListener {
        fun onSoundButtonClick()
        fun onVibrationsButtonClick()
        fun onReturnButtonClick(dialog: GamePauseDialog)
        fun onExitButtonClick(dialog: GamePauseDialog)
}
```

How to implement these listeners and pass them to my dialog instance? I tried using Safe Args and a wrapper (argument in *navigation.xml*), which encapsulated my OnButtonsClickListener and marked it as @Parcelize and Parcelable, but it used to crash at runtime.

Showing dialog:

```
val gamePauseDialogDirection =
            GameFragmentDirections.actionGameFragmentToGamePauseDialog(
                isSoundEnabled,
                areVibrationsEnabled,
                wrapper
            )

findNavController().navigate(gamePauseDialogDirection)
```

Wrapper:

```
@Parcelize
class DialogListenerWrapper (
    val listener: @RawValue DialogInterface.OnDismissListener
) : Parcelable
```

Do you have got any idea how to implement these listeners and pass these it to the dialog using Navigation component?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49891382/479027

Comment: Do you mean to create an instance of my fragment ViewModel in dialog and implement all the listeners in dialog?

Comment: If it crashed at runtime, can you share your stacktrack so we have a better idea of how to help? You can't say something you tried just 'crashed' but not share why.